# Is the command tr capable of translating characters into longer strings?

Tags: shell, string, tr

`tr` is a great tool that can be used to translate `set of characters` into another `set of characters`.

Commands such as `sed , awk, perl` can be used to translate `set of characters` into another **set of strings**, for example, it can translate `<` and `>` **into** `&lt;` and `&gt;`, but it seems unnecessary to use these commands for that purpose!

Is there any other command(s) that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know which shell you are using, but chances are `tr` is not a builtin. It's sure not for me in bash or zsh :) Try running `type tr` to see for yourself.

In all likelyhood, `sed` is the right tool for the job. It's what it was made for. As appropriate `perl` and `awk` too.

If you have very simple cases and if you are working with a string variable instead of a pipeline, you might get away with a real builtin such as using bash's string search and replace on a variable.

```
string="Stuf with <tag> in it."
escaped=${string//</&lt;}
escaped=${escaped//>/&gt;}
echo $escaped
```

Comment: I've fixed the terminology :)

Answer (score 3):

Replacing multiple strings with another set of multiple strings becomes messy if you want to use standard parameter handling. Usually, commands take a set of atomic parameters, and then a set of atomic arguments, and the sequence doesn't matter other than that arguments come after parameters (separated by `--` if ambiguous). How would you construct the synopsis in this case?

Here's a simple function which should do the job for simple replacements:

```
$ trs() {
    local string=$1
    shift
    for replacement in "$@"
    do
        string="$(sed -e "s/$replacement/g" <<< "$string")"
    done
    printf "$string"
}
$ trs '1 2 3' '1/foo' '2 3/bar baz'
foo bar baz
```

Alternatively you could work with pairs of parameters:

```
$ trs() {
    local string=$1
    shift
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]
    do
        string="$(sed -e "s/$1/$2/g" <<< "$string")"
        shift 2
    done
    printf "$string"
}
$ trs '1 2 3' 1 foo '2 3' 'bar baz'
foo bar baz
```

Comment: These are nice functions. I hoped to find one that is readily available on a foreign system.

Comment: By the  way, these wouldn't handle strings containing special strings like `\?` or `&`.

Comment: @Tim Nordenfur: If you only want to replace literals, you should escape it, yes. This approach allows for regular expressions, which of course is another can of worms.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` can be scary, but simple character to string substitution with `sed` isn't really too bad.

To substitute `x` with the string `bar`, do:

`{something-that-outputs-something-on-stdout} | sed -e 's/x/bar/g'`

if it's a file you're wanting to process, you can use:

`sed -e 's/x/bar/g' {filename}`

(The "g" at the end means "global" which means substitute all occurrences in the line and not just the first one)

Comment: I'm not scared of sed; I embrace it. The reason I'm asking is that using simpler tools seems to be generally encouraged, e.g. not `sed`ding when you can `cut`.

Comment: how about not `cat`ing when you can just use `sed`

Comment: @xenoterracide: Good point, edited answer.

Comment: The only thing that I don't like here is that becomes quite difficult to replace a newline `\n` with a string like ` ; ` using `sed`: [sed: How can I replace a newline (\n)? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n) notes that plain `s///` doesn't work, and you have to go into a "pattern space" syntax...

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the longer string will be, the `sed -e s/xx/yy/g` answers are solid.

However, if you wish to be more general and accept any string as input, e.g. from function arguments, you can't use sed: you'd have to escape the string before using it in the regex, which is very hard.

To do this more reliably, you can use this oneliner:

```
python -c '(lambda s: s.stdout.write(s.stdin.read().replace(*s.argv[1:])))(__import__("sys"))'
```

Add it as an alias in .bashrc for easy use:

```
alias trs='python -c '\''(lambda s: s.stdout.write(s.stdin.read().replace(*s.argv[1:])))(__import__("sys"))'\'''
```

and:

```
$ echo /some-path/file | trs -path /dir1/dir2
/some/dir1/dir2/file
```

background: I use this for another alias; `cds`, to emulate zsh's "cd foo bar" behaviour which substitutes `foo` for `bar` in your pwd:

```
$ function cds { cd "$(pwd | trs "$1" "$2")" ; }

$ mkdir -p /tmp/foo /tmp/bar
$ cd /tmp/foo
$ cds foo bar
$ pwd
/tmp/bar
```

This wouldn't work with a `sed` version if I ever passed a `/`, or other non-regex-safe character.